# Dashboard lights dim when I step on accelerator

Tags: battery, alternator, lights, dashboard

[Car: 2001 Kia Sephia, ~107,000 Miles]

I just got a new alternator put in my car, plus had a lot of other work done. Now I notice my lights are dimming on the dashboard when I step on accelerator and turn the heat on. Could it be the battery and shouldn't they have noticed that?Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle? How old is your battery? The battery is the first thing I'd have checked. I've had this *exact* same problem with vehicles before with a bad battery. Take it to a shop and have it load tested. This will give you an idea beyond what a multimeter can tell you as far as the health of the battery.

Comment: Thanks for responding... the car is old.. a 2001 Kia Sephia with 107,000 miles on it. Not sure how old the battery is, but wouldn't they have tested that when diagnosing the alternator problem?

Comment: Not if you didn't ask them to. If they were pretty sure it was the alternator, they may have only focused on it. Have the battery checked, but also ensure the alternator is good as well. It doesn't happen often, but new and/or rebuilt alternators can be bad right from the factory. Wouldn't be the first time I've seen it happen where it's bad. Battery life is usually around 5 years. If yours is older than that, you'll probably want to consider getting a new one anyway just as a preventative maintenance item.

Comment: If you live near an advance auto parts/autozone/etc. they will test your charging system for free.  That's where I would start.  It will help eliminate what @Paulster2 suggested by diagnosing a bad charging system and it will tell you if your battery is bad.  Just make sure you set aside potentially a couple hours to do this (if they happen to need to charge the battery due to bad alternator or something like that).

Comment: Thank you for all the quick responses. I'm going to do as you suggested and get it tested.